Unable to import modules from subpaths in a shared package using esbuild
I'm trying to set up my shared package to allow importing modules from specific subpaths (e.g., @shared/utils, @shared/hooks). To achieve this, I've configured my package.json as follows:
// package.json
{
  // ..
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "default": "./dist/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./utils": {
      "default": "./dist/utils/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/utils/index.d.ts"
    },
    // ..
  }
}

I'm using esbuild as my module bundler, with the following configuration:
// build.mjs
const libBuildOptions = {
  entryPoints: ['./src/**/*'],
  outdir: 'dist',
  tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
  target: 'es6',
  plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
  define,
  format: 'esm', 
  outExtension: { '.js': '.js' }, 
  sourcemap: true 
}

const build = async () => {
  await esbuild.build(libBuildOptions);

  const execAsync = promisify(exec);
  await execAsync('tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist');
};

My source files are structured as follows:
// src/index.ts
export * from './utils';
// ..

// src/utils/index.ts
export * from './testSentry';
export * from './config';
export * from './theme';

With this setup, when I try to import modules from this shared package in other packages, I can only import from the @shared path, not from subpaths like @shared/utils.
Is there a solution to allow importing from subpaths as intended?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Configured package.json with exports field to specify subpaths:

{
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "default": "./dist/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./utils": {
      "default": "./dist/utils/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/utils/index.d.ts"
    }
  }
}


Set up esbuild configuration in build.mjs:

const libBuildOptions = {
  entryPoints: ['./src/**/*'],
  outdir: 'dist',
  tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
  target: 'es6',
  plugins: [nodeExternalsPlugin()],
  format: 'esm', 
  outExtension: { '.js': '.js' }, 
  sourcemap: true 
}

const build = async () => {
  await esbuild.build(libBuildOptions);
  await execAsync('tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --outDir dist');
};


Structured the source files to export from subpaths:

// src/index.ts
export * from './utils';

// src/utils/index.ts
export * from './testSentry';
export * from './config';
export * from './theme';


Tried specifying direct file paths in exports:

{
  "exports": {
    "./utils/date.js": {
      "default": "./dist/utils/date.js",
      "types": "./dist/utils/date.d.ts"
    }
  }
}


Investigated TypeScript configuration:

Checked if tsconfig.json had moduleResolution set to node16 or nodenext.
Considered changing moduleResolution to bundler.



I was expecting to be able to import modules from subpaths like @shared/utils or @shared/hooks, but the imports are only working from the main @shared path. I can import from @extension/shared/dist/utils, but not from @extension/shared/utils as intended.
